# Entity Framework DateTime format when editing entry

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, date, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a `Timetable` model which only has two attributes at the moment, an `Id` and `Date`. It's defined as so:

```
public class Timetable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, Column(TypeName = "Date"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

I then scaffolded some basic CRUD functionality, and thanks to the `DisplayFormat` annotation it's allowing me to create timetables with dates in the `dd/MM/yyyy` format. However, when I edit an existing timetable, the application is populating the `Date` text box with `01/01/2015 00:00:00` (see screenshot).

[image]

Is there any way to make my application only use the date, rather than date and time?

Comment: How are you generating the html - `@Html.EditorFor()` or `TextBoxFor()`?

Comment: The Edit.cshtml page is using `@Html.EditorFor`.

Comment: Then the attribute needs to be `DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyInEditMode=true)]`. Note the format string - it will generate the browsers implementation of a datepicker and display it in the culture of the browser. Note also its not supported in all browsers.

Comment: Ah, perfect. If you add this as an answer I'll accept it. Also, the named parameter is actually `ApplyFormatInEditMode`, and it didn't create a `date` field for my browser's native date picker, I had to add the `DataType(DataType.Date)` annotation for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to render the browsers datepicker (`<input type="date" ..>`) using `EditorFor()` you need the following attributes on the property (note the ISO format means the date will be displayed in accordance with the browser culture)

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

and in the view

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Date)
```

Note the HTML5 date input is not supported in older browsers, and not at all in FireFox - [see comparison here](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/chrome-39/firefox-34/opera-24.html)